# Apache cache not working using load-balanced web servers

Tags: apache-2.2, load-balancing, cache, haproxy

I just started using haproxy (tcp mode because of SSL) to load balance my traffic between two web servers.

When I was using a single server, after images are downloaded for the first time, apache started serving "304 Not Modified" headers. But now I use two web servers and my browser downloads images again everytime I am connected the other web server.

All images on both servers have the same modification date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely running into [ETag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) issues.   Apache's default ETag for static files is calculated using the [filesystem inode #](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#fileetag), so if you have two different servers using two different drives, the files will be tagged differently.

Add on each server something like

```
FileETag MTime Size
```

at the global level to exclude the inode# from the calculation.  Then, just make sure that your clocks are synchronized and the timestamps on all the files are identical and you should be set.